# How do you say, "I would like to join the gym"

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, usage, sport

I just moved to Paris and have found a gym I'd like to join. I see many words for "to join" in French, but not sure which one should be used in this case:

> joindre, unir, se joindre, adhérer, devenir membre, s'inscrire

It seems like s'inscrire may be the closest as it seems to imply enrolling or registering for something. Would this work?

> Je voudrais s'inscrire au gym, s'il vous plaît.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking to the person that manage the gym club, you should say :

> Je souhaite m'inscrire au [cours/club] de gym
>   Je souhaite rejoindre le [cours/club] de gym
>   Je souhaite adhérer au club de gym

Saying "la gym" is not common, you may only say something like

> Je fais de la gym

But you can't say

> Je veux rejoindre la gym

Answer (score 2):

Pour te rendre l'existence plus simple et te permettre de choisir toi-même l'expression que tu jugeras la plus appropriée, voici une liste des différentes traductions proposées ainsi que leur sens exact en lien avec ta question:
joindre, unir, se joindre, adhérer, devenir membre, s'inscrire

- ***joindre*** : Signifie davantage *d'entrer en contact avec le gym*, par exemple, en les appelant pour obtenir de l'information sur leurs forfaits.
- ***unir*** : N'a absolument aucun lien avec l'action que tu as en vue, *c'est un mot qui s'applique davantage aux objets, ou lorsqu'on parle d'un pacte, une union civile*, le fait d'unir deux personnes dans un mariage.
- ***se joindre*** : S'emploie dans le sens de *te joindre à un groupe de personnes qui vont s'entraîner*. Donc, non-applicable à l'action que tu envisage.
- ***adhérer*** / ***s'inscrire*** : Ils sont tout indiqués dans ton cas, car ils vont dans le sens de ce que tu voulais dire. Les deux peuvent s'employer alternativement, car il n'y a qu'une différence étymologique dans leur significations.
- ***devenir membre*** : C'est le motif de ton adhésion ou inscription au gym. *Je m'inscris/adhère au gym afin de devenir membre.*

Donc le verdict c'est que les mots les plus appropriés sont: ***adhérer*** / ***s'inscrire***, par définition.

Pour ce qui est de la phrase spécifique que tu voulais formuler:

> Je voudrais s'inscrire au gym, s'il vous plaît.

Étant donné que tu parles de ton intention de t'inscrire toi-même, `m'` devra être utilisé à la place de `s'`.

> Je voudrais m'inscrire au gym, s'il vous plaît.

En espérant t'avoir mis sur une piste de réflexion intéressante.

Comment: Il serait utile de mentionner que « au gym » est un québécisme qui sera compris mais incorrect à Paris (erreur de genre) où l'on s'attend plutôt à entendre « au cours de gym » ou « au club de gym » déjà mentionnés par @Random. Si l'on souhaite vraiment une formule courte, il faudra dire « à la gym » car gym est un mot féminin : **la** gymnastique.

Comment: Pour préciser pourquoi gym est masculin au Québec : on parle de l'endroit, le gymnase, et non pas de l'activité, la gymnastique.

Comment: Merci à vous deux pour ces précisions intéressantes. Étant québécois, je n'avais pas pensé que le sens de `gym` pouvait varier en France ou au Québec de `gymnastique` à `gymnase` respectivement.

Comment: @jiliagre étant donné qu'on se rend au gymnase (lieu) et non au gymnastique (activité). C'est la France qui fait l'erreur de genre et non le Québec.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur Il n'y a d'erreur de genre ni d'un côté ni de l'autre puisque l'abréviation ne s'applique finalement pas aux mêmes mots. Je n'avais en effet pas pensé à gymnase. Curieusement, en France on n'utilise pas ce mot dans le cas qui nous intéresse ici. Un gymnase est le plus souvent une salle de sport gérée par une mairie au autre collectivité et utilisée en priorité par les écoles, lycées et associations sportives alors que s'il s'agit d'installations privées, on dira plutôt "salle de gym".

Comment: Mais _gym aquatique_ serait n.f. pour la gymnastique et non une salle spécialisée pour la gymnastique aquatique. Le générique sous-jacent pour gymnase est différent selon le sens d'établissement vs. la salle à la fin 19e. Le GDT ne mentionne pas _gym_ à première vue comme étant une particularité au Québec. Est-ce un québécisme ou un anglicisme. C'est sans doute familier à l'oral ? C'est un sujet bien intéressant, et c'est quoi la différence de fonction entre l'entraînement qu'on fait au gym et la _gymnastique de forme_. Et quel serait le rôle de la _salle de remise en forme_. Ah, questions.

Comment: Je ne comprend pas vraiment comment on peut s'inscrire à un supposé gymnase, mais je veux bien croire que ce soit utilisé au Québec. Il s'agit nécessairement ici de la discipline. On s'inscrit à la gym(nastique) comme on s'inscrit à la danse.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Il n'y a pas différence fondamentale entre s'inscrire à la danse, à la gymnastique ou au gymnase. Toutes ces expressions sont des métonymies. C'est au club de gym, de sport ou de fitness que l'on s'inscrit vraiment.